# Zurb Foundation 6 reveal unable to trigger event followed by close event

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

We are alerting a message after close of popups. This was working fine with foundation 4 and now i am trying to upgrade to foundation 6 and it fails to trigger event followed by close of popup.

Foundation 4 (working prototype):

```js
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).foundation();
   $('#reveal_trigger').on("click", function() {
   
    $('#reveal_modal').foundation("reveal","open");
   })
   
   $('#close_trigger').on("click", function() {
    $('#reveal_modal').foundation("reveal","close").one('closed', function ()
     {
      alert("closed");
     });
   });

         })
```

```html
<!doctype html>
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8" />
      <meta http-equiv = "x-ua-compatible" content = "ie=edge" />
      <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0" />
      
      <title>Reveal Basics</title>
      
      <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/4.2.3/css/foundation.css">
      <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/4.2.3/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/4.2.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
   
   </head>

   <body>
      <h2>Reveal Basics Example</h2>  
   <!--<p><a data-reveal-id="reveal_modal">Click Me For A Modal</a></p>-->
      <p><a id="reveal_trigger">Click Me For A Modal</a></p>

   <div class="reveal-modal" id="reveal_modal" data-reveal>
     <h2>Foundation 4</h2>
     <p>Foundation is a family of responsive front-end frameworks that make 
         it easy to design beautiful responsive websites, apps and emails
         that look amazing on any device! 
      <a id="close_trigger">Click to close</a>
     </p>
  
        <button type="button" class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close reveal">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
   </div>

   </body>
   
</html>
```

Foundation 6 (Failing prototype):

```js
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).foundation();
   $('#reveal_trigger').on("click", function() {
   
    $('#reveal_modal').foundation("open");
   });
   
   $('#close_trigger').on("click", function() {
    $('#reveal_modal').foundation("close").one('closed', function ()
     {
      alert('closed');
     });
   });
         })
```

```html
<!doctype html>
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8" />
      <meta http-equiv = "x-ua-compatible" content = "ie=edge" />
      <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0" />
      
      <title>Reveal Basics</title>
      
      <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.0.1/css/foundation.css">
      <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/motion-ui/1.1.1/motion-ui.css">
      <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.0.1/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.0.1/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h2>Reveal Basics Example</h2>
      <!--<p><a data-open="reveal_modal">Click Me For A Modal</a></p> -->
    
   <p><a id="reveal_trigger">Click Me For A Modal</a></p>
   
      <div class="reveal" id="reveal_modal" data-reveal data-animation-in="slide-in-down" data-animation-out="slide-out-up">
        <h2>Foundation 6</h2>
        <p>Foundation is a family of responsive front-end frameworks that make 
         it easy to design beautiful responsive websites, apps and emails
         that look amazing on any device.
   <a id="close_trigger">Click to close</a>
        </p>
         
        <button type="button" class="close-button" aria-label="Close reveal" data-close>
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
   </body>
   
</html>
```

Same code with foundation 6 fails to trigger event after close.

Answer (score 0):

The events have changed. Upgrading from 4 to 6 are two major breaking versions.

It is now `open.zf.reveal` and `closed.zf.reveal`, see https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html#js-events

The method is `.foundation('close')`, see https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html#close

Generally speaking you should use Foundation 6.5 / latest. The docs are for this version, not 6.0. And many things have changed, including breaking changes in 6.x.

Comment: Yes, i was able to find this information in foundation reveal docs. And tried out with closed.zf.reveal event capture and facing issue with this event not recognized first time.  It looks like after it runs first time the closed.zf.reveal event is registered and it is working as expected in followed close actions. And i am trying upgrade with latest 6.5.3 release.